# How can I access files downloaded from firefox on ubuntu touch in convergence mode

Tags: firefox, ubuntu-touch, mir

Issue occurred on my BQ Aquaris M10 Ubuntu Edition with the latest update applied as of Monday 22nd of April 16.

When I download a file in firefox in convergence mode firefox can see that it's in the ~/Download folder but none of the other apps e.g. the file browser or the terminal can see the file.

Does anyone know how I can see this file or transfer it from where ever it is to somewhere useful ? I presume this has something to do with firefox running in a container for Xmir but I can't be sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm writing from my M10 and I found the downloaded files under this folder in the main user's home

```
.local/share/libertine-container/user-data/puritine/Downloads/
```