# Ubuntu Touch: where are downloaded files stored?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, files, downloads, browser

When I download something with the default browser or Firefox, I cant seem to find where the files are downloaded to. Not /home/Downloads, thats for sure. Does anyone know where the files are downloaded to? I already searched in some places and tried search here on AU but couldnt find an answer.

Comment: I guess it would be `/home/USERNAME/Downloads`, not just `/home/Downloads`

Comment: You are right, I meant /home/USERNAME/Downloads but got confused by the File Manager app.

Still, Firefox doesnt save it there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I access files downloaded from firefox on ubuntu touch in convergence mode](http://askubuntu.com/questions/760609/how-can-i-access-files-downloaded-from-firefox-on-ubuntu-touch-in-convergence-mo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are in

```
.local/share/libertine-container/user-data/puritine/Downloads/
```

Comment: Wow, that is a non-obvious location. But thanks, this did solve my question! :-)

Comment: It's to do with the how the X apps are sandboxed away from the rest of the System, seems very silly to me, I have a symlink to it in my Downloads directory

Comment: I had not even thought of that, but symlinking is a great idea indeed. Gonna do that right away, thank you very, very much! :-)